# Incorrect syntax near AS error in user defined function when trying to create an alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, alias, azure-data-studio

I created a user-defined function where you put in a code for an object and it finds the minimum of the prices. I'm having trouble on trying to define an alias `'Lowest Price'` for the output column.

Every time I use `AS 'Lowest Price'` I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

```
CREATE FUNCTION findlowprice (@oc AS INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @return INT

    SELECT @return = MIN(price) AS 'Lowest Price'
    FROM online_warehouse
    WHERE @oc = object_code

    RETURN @return
END;
```

I tried `AS 'Lowest Price'` in almost every line except for Line 4 `BEGIN` and line 10 `END;` and I still get the error.

Is there a way to define an alias for the output column in a user-defined function?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: If this is for SQL Server, then you cannot do this. This is a **scalar function** that doesn't return a result set with columns (where you *could* define a column alias) - it returns only a single atomic value (of type `INT`). You reference that value by means of the **name** of that function - so if you want a different name, just name your function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you *want* or *need* an alias? The value that is returned from the function is coming from the value that is in `@return`, and that value is totally independent of whatever alias you would put on the expression, assuming you would be allowed to do so.

A `SELECT` can be used for two things:

1. Setting one or more variables, as you are doing.
2. Producing a result set, with rows and columns.

Only for the second variant it is possible to use a column alias. A column alias is related to a result set that is being created. The first variant does not create a result set, so column aliases make no sense and are not allowed.

As a further example, if you would try to combine the two variants, e.g. `SELECT @return = MIN(price), someOtherValue FROM online_warehouse` then you would see this error:

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

This shows that the two variants are actually distinguished by the compiler (and that they can't be combined).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest adding semicolons after the DECLARE statement and the WHERE clause. The error could be happening because you assigned a variable within the SELECT statement. Maybe using alias when using the function would be helpful.

```
CREATE FUNCTION findlowprice (@oc AS INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @return INT;

    SELECT @return = MIN(price) AS 'Lowest Price'
    FROM online_warehouse
    WHERE @oc = object_code;

    RETURN @return
END;
```

Comment: Tried this, so far I still get the "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'." error still. But thanks for the help